# Limitar Decimales en un JSON que aparte de números contiene letras

Tags: php, mysql

estoy trabajando con php y phpmyadmin

este es un pedazo de un registro-ejemplo de los que guardo en un campo que le doy tipo de longtext:

```
"infSensores":{"Largo":"58.00","Vacio":"0.03","Lleno":"4.94"},"infTanques":{"forma":"cilindro","largo":120,"altodiametro":61.5,"var":"0","litros100":453.999000000000023646862246096134185791015625...
```

eso es solo un pedazo de ahí en adelante siguen mas valores "litrosxcm" donde todos mis litros (los cuales cuentan con decimal) se extienden a 44 decimales, yo la verdad solo ocupo como 3 o 2 decimales pero no se porque al momento de guardar se vuelven tantos y no se como limitarlo porque no creo poder cambiar el tipo de campo porque ocupo también valores alfabéticos.

Aquí lo importante es el reducir esa cantidad de decimales.

cabe aclarar que en los headers al momento de ver lo que se va a mandar a guardar salen los decimales bien, sin incluir los 39 de sobra.

Comment: De donde sale la informacion de `infSensores` y como la guardas?

Comment: @alanfcm la guardo en otra tabla y la guardo con tipos decimal (10,2)

Comment: @alanfcm el de "litros100" por ejemplo lo traigo de un FLOAT, y los que le siguen de ahi lo traigo de otro json con tipo TEXT

Comment: No entiendo muy bien cuál es el problema. ¿Esos datos están todos así en una sola columna de la tabla? ¿Qué hay que hacer luego con los datos? ¿Cómo lo estás haciendo (código)?

Comment: Si, todos esos datos están así en una solo columna de la tabla,
esos datos después se utilizaran para calculos, y todo en el Json ayuda a esos calculos. 
Esta de esa manera para solo visitar un campo y de ahi obtener todo lo necesario para hacer los cálculos de esa parte.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es limitar esos datos a la hora de guardar, debes mostrarnos el código que usas para guardar esos valores en la base de datos, o incluso el código que usas para producir esos valores. Si quieres limitarlos en la lectura, puedes usar `json_decode` por ejemplo y no tendrías problemas, te redondearía esos números largos a dos o tres cifras decimales.